# The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned: is that impossible

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have defined the following procedure in PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteFromStudyCase(studycase_id IN NUMBER)
IS
   VAL_CARRIER_ID_GLOBAL  NUMBER(19,0);
   EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL      NUMBER(19,0);
   INVEST_TASK_ID_GLOBAL  NUMBER(19,0);
BEGIN

-- Fill the variables
SELECT IT.ID into INVEST_TASK_ID_GLOBAL
  FROM T_INVESTIGATIONTASK IT
  WHERE IT.STUDYCASE_ID = studycase_id;

SELECT EO.ID into EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL 
  FROM T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT EO
  WHERE EO.INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID = INVEST_TASK_ID_GLOBAL;

SELECT VC.ID into VAL_CARRIER_ID_GLOBAL
  FROM T_VALIDATIONCARRIER VC
  WHERE VC.IA_ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL;

....many DELETE statements...

END deleteFromStudyCase;
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
BEGIN
  DELETEFROMSTUDYCASE(30111);
END;
```

At runtime it fails with this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "DELETEFROMSTUDYCASE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 2
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Meaning that one of the selects is returning more than just one value as expected. I tried so to run the select statements separately to see which one was the problem but:

```
SELECT IT.ID
  FROM T_INVESTIGATIONTASK IT
  WHERE IT.STUDYCASE_ID = 30111;
```

is returning only 10053.

```
SELECT EO.ID
  FROM T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT EO
  WHERE EO.INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID = 10053;
```

is returning only 933.

```
SELECT VC.ID
  FROM T_VALIDATIONCARRIER VC
  WHERE VC.IA_ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = 933;
```

is returning only 12.

Since this part of my database has a tree structure I have also created the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteFromInvestigationTask(invest_task_id IN NUMBER)
IS
  VAL_CARRIER_ID_GLOBAL NUMBER(19,0);
  EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL NUMBER(19,0);
BEGIN

-- Fill the variables
SELECT EO.ID into EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL 
  FROM T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT EO
  WHERE EO.INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID = invest_task_id;

SELECT VC.ID into VAL_CARRIER_ID_GLOBAL 
  FROM T_VALIDATIONCARRIER VC
  WHERE VC.IA_ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL;

...many DELETE statements...
```

And this one works correctly.
So the other one should work, why do I continue to get that error? What else could it be?

Comment: well how we supposed to help you ? run the debug in the procudre and follow the results you can debug in this way too : i rename the procedure to deleteFromStudyCaseTest and compile it, if the error presists, i remove the delete,if still error i remove the 3rd select, and i try with first and 2nd if still presist I try to get the output of query and understand what are the result is outputing. maybe someone has access to the database and adding data ?

Comment: The second procedure uses only SELECTs 2 and 3. This provides evidence that the troubles are caused by the SELECT Nr. 1. The same evidence proviedes the error stack, pointing to the line 9 (which is the first SELECT).  Manually running the query will provide the answer - check that you are in the same database, with the same user and that all transactions are `COMMIT`ed.

Comment: If you are sure that only one record is returned in your select, then try and test using:  SELECT MAX(EO.ID) into EST_OBJ_ID_GLOBAL etc etc.. This will also force the result to return one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. 
In the first procedure, the parameter name is `studycase_id` which is also the name of a column in the table `T_INVESTIGATIONTASK` so the `WHERE` condition  `IT.STUDYCASE_ID = studycase_id` is wrong: that's why the first `SELECT` is failing. I changed the parameter name in `study_case_id` and solved my problem.

Comment: Good spot. You can prefix parameters with the name of the procedure, e.g. `deleteFromStudyCase.studycase_id`. Or what most people do, which is use a naming convention such as `p_studycase_id` for parameters.

Comment: Putting a `p` for "parameters" sounds good enough. I will probably adopt this convention for the future.